# Open gallery when select a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add some code in order to open a gallery when a thumbnail is selected.
Right now i have this line

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/idee-bianco.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/idee-bianco.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/idee-bianco.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
  ........

    </div>
```

Now, i would like to open a gallery or carousel whenever a thumbnail is selected.
It's a portfolio so each thumbnail represent something different, for example, photography, video, illustration, and so on.

Bootstrap's CSS is mostly default, same for js.
Thanks

Comment: You haven't even written a line to do so. Try something and then post the code if it doesn't work.

Comment: That's the thumbnail code. I don't know how or where to start, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Add a class to the gallery and style it as display: none. On click of thumbnail, just change the style to display: block

Comment: So, after the img class I have to open a new div class gallery amd I right? And display none. When active display block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-lg-12 gallery">
    <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/idee-bianco.png" alt="" onclick = "Show()">
    </a>
</div>

<style>
.gallery{
    display: none;   // gallery is not visible normally
 }
</style>
<script>
function Show(){
     document.getElementsByClass('gallery').style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

Here when user clicks an image, you are calling the show function which manipulates the display property of the class gallery. Remember that this function will affect all elements belonging to class 'gallery'. Use id of you intend to have only one such gallery on your page.

Comment: Done, but i need some more advice. In my bootstrap (both css and js) i don't have any gallery preset, so, i was thinking about the carousel item to show on click, maybe using all width in mobile and a little less in desktop or tablet.
Right now when i click on the image, my page scrolls back to the top, and it's ok, i don't have any href, but, where exactly i have to put the other code lines? I mean, the gallery one, where i'll put the image i want in that gallery.

Comment: Just create a div tag, assign it a class. add styling properties and place your code inside that.